# Split a column of strings into 3 separate columns with Pandas

Tags: python, string, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to separate a dataframe column in three parts, but I'm getting this error:

```
too many values to unpack
```

This is my code:

```
dimensions['store'], dimensions['country'], dimensions['store_nick'] = dimensions['dimension_value'].str.split('@').str
```

This is my column value:

```
'Store@Country@StoreNick'
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend splitting first with `str.split` and *then* concatenating, using `pd.concat`:

```
df = dimensions['dimension_value'].str.split('@', expand=True)
df.columns = ['store', 'country', 'store_nick']    
dimensions = pd.concat([dimensions, df], axis=1)
```

`expand=True` parameter will cause splits to occupy separate columns.